# Getting all the content of a content type in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-content-types

I made a content type name as **Jobs** in drupal 7 and in Jobs content type i have added multiple multiple contents now i want to get all the content types which are related to jobs.
Can it be possible using custom query or any inbuilt drupal function or module..

Please Suggest

Thanks in advance !!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can easily get a list of all your content types "jobs" contents you created by using [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module. From there, you can do a lot of scenarios but it depends on your final goal.

Programmatically, you can search for all your conten types "jobs" existing in your DB within a hook or whatever you are doing.

```
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();
$result = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
  ->entityCondition('bundle', 'jobs')
  ->execute();
$nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($result['node']));
```

Hope it helped.

Comment: Is there by any chance a module to do this?

Comment: @Chris-Jr As I said in the first part of my answer, you can easily achieve that using Views module.

Comment: @Djouuuuh, sorry, I realize that was vague. I meant is there a module which allows for us to use shortcode/tags to access raw content type nodes without writing the php ourselves? In a similar way to how [Insert View] (https://www.drupal.org/project/insert_view) works for Views.